# How can I convert a wallet.aes.json file from Blockchain.info to a wallet.dat file?

Tags: wallet, blockchain.info, wallet.dat

I'd like to convert my Blockchain.info wallet to a local Bitcoin-qt wallet. How can I do that? (I am fine with using command line tools.)

Answer (score 1):

The way I go about it is as follows:

1. Login to Blockchain.info and choose **export**
2. Export data as **BITCOIN QT**
3. Note the private key in the form *5Hxxxx* or *5Kxxxx* or *5Lxxxxx*. Copy and paste this string (or hand write it to be safer; it's case sensitive and has no 0/O, l/I)
4. Open Bitcoin QT; click *help>Console*
5. Type *importprivkey* *PRIVKEY* *NAME* where *PRIVKEY* is what was copied and pasted and name is the name for the address eg *MAIN1*
6. If wallet.dat is encrypted you'll need to type: *walletpassphrase PASSWORD 180*
7. *Be sure to encrypt your wallet again*
8. Move funds from Blockchain wallets to a new address in case you're concerned about malware monitoring copy/paste

Comment: Anyone want to comment why the above is not right?

Comment: `Be sure to encrypt your wallet again` What do you mean? It will automatically re-lock after 180 seconds.

Comment: The above doesn't work; Multibit doesn't accept the json file format. Blockchain.info does though (the website).